# When using Griddle.js, is it possible to sort a column using values from a metadata column?

Tags: sorting, reactjs, griddle

## Is it possible to sort one column via values of another hidden (metadata) column?

#### Why is this  desired?

1. When Sorting dollar values, it is desirable and more consistent if we sort by numerical values instead of string/formatted dollar values.
2. When Sorting non-zero padded values with prefix/suffixes, sorting would only work through an index of sorts.